# Xamarin Auth plugin Oauth2 and Google sign in

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I've found a bunch of great tutorials on how to use the Xamarin auth component to authenticate using Oauth2 via Facebook and Google. It seems straightforward and I have no problems getting it working with Facebook. However, using Google always produces this screen:

[image]

I set up the credential at the google developer site per the tutorial and I've tried multiple tutorials / git hub projects and they all produce the same result, no login. Does / will Xamarin.auth work with Google authentication?

Thanks.

Here's one I worked through but there's a bunch of them:

https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/google-services/SigninQuickstart/

Comment: Does `Xamarin.Auth` work with Google OAuth2? Yes and no, the currently released *stable* version : **No**, *but* there is an alpha version of `Xamarin.Auth` that supports Chrome CustomTabs and thus would be allowed by Google : see the following for more details:  https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/issues/144 If you are interested in using Chrome CustomTabs directly, I ported Google's sample as a C# reference source: https://github.com/sushihangover/SushiHangover.GoogleChrome.CustomTabs.Shared